# ¿como programas en Surveytogo?

Tags: javascript, c#, survey

La encuesta consiste en un sku mas un precio de entrada y un precio de salida, necesito que los textbox donde se ingresa la información siempre estén visibles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<script>

this.textBox.Visible = true;

</script>
```

este era mi codigo